# Example of a meromorphic function in $\mathbb{C}$ but not in $\mathbb{C}_{\infty}$

Tags: complex-analysis

I need to produce an example of a meromorphic function on $\mathbb{C}$ but not meromorphic on the Riemann sphere $\mathbb{C}_{\infty}$.
Will this work: $f(z)=e^z-1/z$?
Other examples are welcome. Thank you.

Comment: You probably mean $\mathcal C$ rather than $\mathbb C$; the latter denotes the complex numbers.

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen I dont understand really.

Comment: Katuk: @Marc seems to have thought that you were talking about the function spaces $\mathcal C$ and $\mathcal C^\infty$ rather then the complex plane and Riemann sphere. (He might have been been confused by the strange wording "meromorphic function in $\mathbb C$" rather than "on $\mathbb C$" or "function that is meromorphic on/in $\mathbb C$", since "in $\mathbb C$" modifies "meromorphic" rather than "function").

Comment: Indeed I was put off by "in $\mathbb C$" since $\mathbb C$ contains no functions at all. I've now edited the question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I just wanted to note that your example $e^z-\frac1z$ works but so does the simpler $e^z$.  (You can add in the $-\frac1z$ in order to put a pole in $\mathbb C$ if you like, but typically holomorphic functions are considered particular instances of meromorphic functions).

Comment: Yes, of course. But the most important feature of a meromorphic function is that it has poles(possibly none). So I don't think an entire function is a typical example of meromorphic functions.

Comment: Morgan's remark that we can take a holomorphic function  is very clever precisely *because* it emphasises  that although meromorphic functions immediately evoke poles, actually you don't *need* a function with poles to answer the question: the simplest  (counter)examples are the best: +1

Answer (score 4):

Meromorphic functions on  $\mathbb{C}_{\infty}$ are rational functions.
Let $f(z)$ be an entire function which is not polynomial, for example $e^z$ or sin $z$.
Let $g(z)$ be an entire function which is not constant $0$.
Suppose $f(z)/g(z)$ is not a rational function, for example let $g(z)$ be a polynomial.
Then both $f(z)/g(z)$ and $g(z)/f(z)$ are meromorphic on $\mathbb{C}$ but not meromorphic on $\mathbb{C}_{\infty}$.

Comment: Ah! Thanks, I should have applied the result  a function which is   a meromorphic  in the extended complex plane must be  a rational function.